# radix sort on array of 6 digit non-negative numbers

Tags: java, arrays, radix-sort

I can't figure out how to remove the values from an array of queues and place them into an array of ints using radix sort.

This is the code I have right now:

```
 public static void radixSort(int[] a) {
  //Create an array of 10 empty array queues
  Queue[] arr =  new Queue[a.length];

  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      arr[i] = new ArrayQueue();

  for (int place = 1; place <= 100000; place *= 10) {
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
          arr[i].add(selectDigit(a[i],place));
      for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
         a[j] = (Integer) arr[j].iterator().next();     
  } 
 }
```

place is an int that is supposed to be (1,10,100,1000,100000) and it refers to the place in a 6 digit number such as for place = 1 in 684720 the returned digit from selectDigit would be 0 (1s place) and etc. selectDigit takes the parameter (int digit, int place). Right now I have an empty array, arr, where each index holds an empty arrayQueue. for each digit in the array, a, I add the proper 1s,10s,100s, etc, value into the proper index of arr[i]. In the part I'm not sure about I'm supposed to move each of the values from the queue back into the array, a but I'm not sure how I can accomplish that.

Edit: the revised code above produces the following output (still incorrect) which basically has the last digit in each index of a (before sort) but not the 10s, 100s, 1000s, etc places.

```
Array before sort: 602408, 183305, 695804, 934237, 285465, 860846, 196873, 139853, 444089, 594823, 436004, 812525, 302271, 104933, 811084, 350006, 115421, 582466, 192803, 163908, 380316, 734056, 595086, 314881, 784318, 959734, 834553, 982188, 272574, 98232
Array after  sort: 8, 5, 4, 7, 5, 6, 3, 3, 9, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 6, 6, 1, 8, 4, 3, 8, 4, 2
```

Comment: Sounds like this is over engineered (waaaay too complicated). What is it you're *actually* trying to achieve? Ie in English, forgetting about the implementation for a second.

Comment: Take an array of six digit numbers and sort them from lowest to highest.

Comment: Right now I'm getting a nullpointerexception at arr[i].add(selectDigit(a[i], place)); probably because I haven't initialized arr[] properly. How can I initialize it correctly?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking for radix sort because this is a large array of 6-digit integers, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Each index in the array holds a 6 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Your method should be deleted and you should just call this instead:

```
Arrays.sort(a);
```